# In Java, how do I *interruptably* read/write a subprocess's standard input/output?

Tags: java, process, interrupted-exception

I have a Java program that communicates with an SMT solver implementing the [SMT-LIB](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/) standard. My program starts the SMT solver in interactive mode as a subprocess using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It then sends commands to the solver via the subprocess's standard input stream (accessed through `Process.getOutputStream()`) and reads the results via the subprocess's standard output stream (accessed through `Process.getInputStream()`).

Since solving NP-hard problems can take a while, my program normally spends a lot of time blocked in `read()` calls waiting for the SMT solver to return a result.

I am currently working on a GUI for my program. The GUI does the interaction with the SMT solver on a background thread so as not to block the foreground GUI thread while the solver is running.

I would like for the user to be able to cancel the operation partway through, terminating the SMT solver process and finishing the background operation with any partial results that have been generated.

Options I've considered so far:

- My first thought was to use [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) from the GUI thread to interrupt the blocking I/O on the background thread, and have the background thread recognize when it has been interrupted while blocking on a `read()` call and terminate the subprocess using `Process.destroy()` before finishing its task. The problem is, as far as I can tell, calling `Thread.interrupt()` on a thread that is blocked on process I/O does not interrupt the block! I was hoping it would throw [InterruptedIOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html) or work like the interruptable I/O in the `java.nio` package, but it doesn't seem to.
- My next idea was to have the GUI check whether the subprocess is running via a synchronized variable and, if it is, kill the process from the GUI thread. This would cause the `read()` call on the background thread to act as if end-of-input were reached, I think. This is really ugly design-wise though, since I'm already using `Thread.interrupt()` to communicate cancelation requests to the background thread during other operations and I don't see why I should need a special case in the GUI logic for process blocking vs. other types of blocking.
- The only other alternative I've been able to think of is to have a *second* background thread that handles communication with the subprocess and just relays communication from/to the main background thread. When the GUI calls `Thread.interrupt()` on the main background thread, the main background thread jumps out of its monitor blocking on the second background thread, kills the process that the second background thread is blocking on, and then proceeds as normal. This seems way more complicated than it needs to be, though.

**QUESTION**

What is the preferred means of asynchronously interrupting a thread that is blocked on I/O with a process?

If it matters, I'm on Windows 7 running Java 1.8.0u60.

Comment: `InputStreams` are not interruptible. You will have to kill the process.

Comment: do you have any (code-level) control over the process which is running the SMT solver code?  if so, i would change it so that you can send it a command to interrupt the current computation (assuming the library itself supports interruption).

Comment: @jtahlborn Not in general, because the user is supposed to be able to drop in any solver executable that implements the SMT-LIB standard, and the standard is entirely specified in terms of pipe interaction as far as I'm aware.

Comment: a quick glance at the spec seems to imply that you should be able to use the "reset" or "exit" commands to accomplish what you want?

Comment: are you using a _single_ thread to handle both input and output with the sub-process?

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://blog.headius.com/2013/06/the-pain-of-broken-subprocess.html

Comment: @EJP So you're saying that if I want to interrupt a thread that is blocking on process I/O and I _don't_ want to kill the process, I'm out of luck without resorting to native calls?

Comment: @jtahlborn Yeah, I have one background thread that writes to the solver, reads the response, and decides on the next action. I'm guessing that sending `(exit)` to the solver while it is still working on a `(check-sat)` is not guaranteed to cause the solver to exit until the `(check-sat)` is finished, which is why killing the process seems like the natural option.

Comment: you shouldn't need native calls.  you can call `Process.destroy()`.

Comment: A non-answer, but you know there is jSMTLIB which already does communication for you? (https://github.com/smtlib/jSMTLIB) Also there is Java-SMT (https://github.com/sosy-lab/java-smt) doing communication on API level.